# How to manage different versions of postgresql on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

Basically, when I run `psql --version`, I get `PostgreSQL 9.5.4`. But with `sudo su postgres` and `psql`, the terminal throws me `psql (10.0)`. Could anyone tell me what exactly going on here?

What makes me more confused is that there's no `./9.5` under the directory `/etc/postgresql/`. The only version I manually installed on my machine is postgresql-10, and I have no clue why "9.5" pops up when I run `psql --version`

And if I had multiple postgresql (i.e. `postgresql-9.5`, `postgresql-9.6`) installed, what is the correct way to use a certain version of postgresql?

Comment: See `pg_wrapper` for how it works

Comment: Okay. This `pg_wrapper: command not found`. lol

Comment: `man pg_wrapper`. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pg_wrapper.1.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the `PostgreSQL 9.5.4` when using `psql --version`, try to locate the path of psql using either of these `which psql` or `locate psql`.

You should be able to see which installation of postgres is providing the output.

Comment: Great help. `which psql` gives me `/home/jingw222/anaconda3/bin/psql`. But then I wonder what's different between this `psql` coming with anaconda and postgresql.

Comment: Well, the versions are different. For more details, try connecting to both the databases and check inside.